# Fetch Data from endpoint and show on Listview Horizontal to implement Slide

Tags: flutter

So I am learning Flutter again and there is something i need to know i want to fetch data from a REST endpoint and show it on a horizontal Listview.

The Endpoint is [here](https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/address/addr.php) which shows different addresses, coin types , balances.

The source code looks like this :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//Account Details

class AccountDetails {
  String? address;
  String? balance;
  String? coin_name;

  AccountDetails({
    this.address,
    this.balance,
    this.coin_name,
  });

  AccountDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    address = json['address'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    coin_name = json['coin_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['address'] = address;
    data['balance'] = balance;
    data['coin_name'] = coin_name;
    return data;
  }
}

//Transaction Details.

class TransactionDetails {
  String? avatar;
  String? name;
  String? date;
  String? amount;

  TransactionDetails({
    this.avatar,
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.amount,
  });

  TransactionDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    name = json['name'];
    date = json['date'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['avatar'] = avatar;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['amount'] = amount;
    return data;
  }
}

//Transaction Details stuff

Future<List<TransactionDetails>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => TransactionDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

// Account Details stuff.

Future<List<AccountDetails>> fetchAccountDetails() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/address/addr.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => AccountDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "My Bank",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 27),
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ), //gap or use Padding widget
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), //apply padding to all four sides
              child: Text(
                "Hello Emeka!",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ), //gap
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 175,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 230, 230)
                                .withOpacity(0.8),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 3,
                            offset: Offset(0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$ 5200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 230, 230)
                                .withOpacity(0.8),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 3,
                            offset: Offset(0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$ 1200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Text(
                "Recent Transactions",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
                    future: fetchAlbum(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                                ),
                                title:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                                trailing: Text(
                                    snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
                              );
                            });
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                      }
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }))
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

So what I want it to do, once it spools the information from the endpoint, which contains the address, balance and coin_name I want it to display on the slider navigator. Please advice on how to go about this. I am new to this , and I would like to know.

Comment: you want to display your address API data inside horizontal list view?

Comment: the balance , the coin name, then a center header should say "Wallet balance"

Comment: please check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIt9p.png) image is it correct?

Comment: All information show as I want it Sir
But i want the Balance to be in the Middle, Bolded, say 800 font weight and white, the coin name at the extreme top left, address at the bottom , the address font should also be smaller than the balance etc

Comment: Can you add your exact design?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it looks thus https://i.postimg.cc/wMbVg1Pb/Screenshot-1664348063.png

Comment: I have this design but I want where to put AddressDetails Data ? I mean you put this data inside this green card like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIt9p.png) image

Comment: Ok it should look like this https://i.postimg.cc/hvrYx8jy/122.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

Your `AddressDetails` class

```
class AddressDetails {
  String? address;
  String? balance;
  String? coinName;

  AddressDetails({
    this.address,
    this.balance,
    this.coinName,
  });

  AddressDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    address = json['address'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    coinName = json['coin_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['address'] = address;
    data['balance'] = balance;
    data['coin_name'] = coinName;

    return data;
  }
}
```

Your API call:

```
 Future<List<AddressDetails>> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/address/addr.php',
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = json.decode(response.body);
      return result.map((e) => AddressDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          child: FutureBuilder<List<AddressDetails>>(
            future: fetchAlbum(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      width: 319,
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color:
                                  const Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 230, 230)
                                      .withOpacity(0.8),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 3,
                              offset: const Offset(
                                  0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9)),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            'Account Balance',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                snapshot.data![index].balance.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                snapshot.data![index].coinName.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data![index].address.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: I wish i can Hug you! I am getting your Linkedin. I thank you so so much!

Comment: Please try to upvote this answer

Comment: Done Already! Thank you. I sent you a mail too!

Comment: please refer [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) URL and upvote my answer click on up arrow

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could do but since you are using `FutureBuilder` for your `TransactionDetails`, here also you should wrap your slider navigation with `FutureBuilder` of type `List<AccountDetails>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder to call the api and use a ListView to display it horizontally.
[image: End Result]

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 175,
  child: FutureBuilder<List<AccountDetails>>(
    future: fetchAccountDetails(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text('Could not get data'),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<AccountDetails> accounts = snapshot.data!;
        return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: accounts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            width: 319,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 230, 230)
                        .withOpacity(0.8),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: const Offset(
                        0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9)),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(accounts[index].coin_name ?? ''),
                  Text(
                    '\$ ${(accounts[index].balance ?? 0).toString()}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                                accounts[index].address ?? '')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return const SizedBox();
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

Hope it helps. Happy Fluttering! You are doing great.

Comment: Account details

Comment: its account details i need put in a Slider

Comment: I have updated the code as of your suggestion. Hope it helps. Consider ticking as answer.